# Can't add a color to text when using .setText() method

Tags: android

**[SOLVED]** Here's the code that solved my problem:

`answerTextViewEasy.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.correct_answer));`

---

**PROBLEM:**

I'm trying to add a textcolor to be displayed together with the `.setText`-method. Here's what I'm trying to use but it gives me two errors when I try using following code (check below). First one is over `getColor`, saying it requires min. API 23 (I'm currently using 15). Second one gives the warning "can't resolve method `getTheme`".

Anyone got a tip how to by pass `getColor` and possible use another method that works for API 15 and how I would go around and solve the red error on `getTheme`as well?

```
answerTextViewEasy.setText(answerText);
answerTextViewEasy.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.correct_answer, getContext().getTheme()));

answerTextViewEasy.setText(answerText);
answerTextViewEasy.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.incorrect_answer, getContext().getTheme()));
```

.

Color codes: `correct_answer = #00CC00` and
`incorrect_answer = #FF0000.` For context here's how I've used the coding:

.

**Here's my Java-file:**

```
private void checkCorrectness (String chosenCountry) {
        if (chosenCountry.equals (countries.get (currentCountryIndex).split (".png")[0])) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= correctAnswer; i++) {
                currentScore = currentScore + i;
            }//for-loop ends here
            correctAnswer++;
            currentScore++;
            //String answer = Integer.toString(correctAnswer);
            //correctAnswerTextView.setText("Correct Answers: " + answer);
            String score = Integer.toString(currentScore);
            currentScoreTextView.setText(score);
            String answerText = chosenCountry;
            answerTextViewEasy.setText(answerText);
            answerTextViewEasy.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.correct_answer, getContext().getTheme()));
        }else {
            currentLives--;
            String lives = Integer.toString(currentLives);
            currentLivesTextView.setText(lives);
            answerTextViewEasy.setText("Incorrect!");
            answerTextViewEasy.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.incorrect_answer, getContext().getTheme()));
        }//else ends here
            try {
                randomize ();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }//try-loop ends here
    }//checkCorrectness ends here
```

Answer (score 0):

After the version 23, the old getColor method which only has parameter color id is deprecated. 
You should use this function for supporting all versions.

```
    public static final int getColor(Context context, int id) {
    final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (version >= 23) {
        return ContextCompatApi23.getColor(context, id);
    } else {
        return context.getResources().getColor(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Abdullahu: Where exacly you suggest that I put this code? So far where I tried it gave me error: "cannt resolve ContextCompatApi23".

Comment: @FisnikB. ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),id); could you change it with this one ? Your problem seems like version and deprecated methods, but are you sure of sending the right image ID ?

Comment: Solved my problem: `answerTextViewEasy.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.correct_answer));`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ContextCompat` to get color:

```
answerTextViewEasy.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.correct_answer));
```

Read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html for more detail.

Comment: N.: thanks for the respond, however your code throws me an red error on `getContext`. Says it can't resolve the method.

Comment: `getContext()` is used for `Fragment`. If you're in an `Activity`, just pass `this`

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
    ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.correct_answer)

Comment: Like this `answerTextViewEasy.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.correct_answer));` - this throws me an error, "can't resolve method `getContext`.

Comment: Solved: needed to replace `getContext` with `getApplicationContext`